# JS: I got a test task, I don’t know how to do it. Can you tell me what are the options for solving this task?

Tags: javascript

Company has N people. Many of them are friends. Also, interesting fact is that friends of friends are also friends. You need to find out how much friends has a particular person in the company.

Input data

Function should receive next params: N - number of people in the company S - a specific number of person Matrix N lines contain N numbers consisting of ones and zeros. And the unit standing in the i-th row and j-th column ensures that people with numbers i and j - friends, and 0 - expresses uncertainty.

Output data

Function should return number of the certain friends of the person with the S number, remembering transitive friendship.

```
Example1:

N = 3 
S = 1
Matrix =    0  1  0
            1  0  1
            0  1  0
Result: 2


Example2:

N = 5 
S = 2
Matrix =    0  0  0  0  0 
            0  0  1  0  0
            0  1  0  0  1
            0  0  0  0  1
            0  0  1  1  0 
Result: 3
```

Comment: @Vasya Please add some sudo code. Or something you have tried.

Comment: Please read about [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) For more information, please refer to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is very clearly a homework problem, I won't give you code you can just copy-paste. However, I will offer guidance. Each friendship between two people represents a connection between them, and you can use a [quick-union](http://researchhubs.com/post/computing/algorithm-1/quick-union.html) to generate friendship components. Then, you can find the size of the component that the person is in, subtract 1, and that's the number of friends he has.

Alternatively, if you only need to find the friends for one person, you can maintain an array of friends and initialize that with the immediate friends of that person. Then, you can recurse onto every friend, and if they have any friends not in the array then you add that person to the array and recurse onto them. This will be faster than the first approach.